# how to use a jsonfiy object in assertions?

Tags: json, unit-testing, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to unit test some code, and want to assert that the jsonify output of the code is correct.  here is what I have so far.

```
def test_get_ticket(self):
    with self.app.test_request_context('/?main_id=14522&user_id=82'):
        methodOutput = brain_get_ticket.get_ticket({'main_id': {1: 0}, 'status': {'Closed': 0},
                                                    'available': {'False': 0}}, "main_id, status, available",
                                                   ['main_id', 'status', 'available'])
        correct_return_output = json.dumps(dict(
            to_be_working_on_last_id=0,
            to_be_working_on_id=6,
            information={'status': {'Closed': 1}, 'available': {'False': 1}, 'main_id': {1: 1}}
        ))
        self.assertEquals(json.loads(methodOutput.data()), correct_return_output, "output was: " + str(methodOutput) + " it should be: " + str(correct_return_output))
```

the output i'm getting is :

```
self.assertEquals(json.loads(methodOutput.data()), correct_return_output)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

any suggestions????

Solved:

the main problem was that I was using data as if it was a method, not a descriptor, like Martijn said.  Also changing the correct_return_output to a dictionary instead of a jsonify object to compare to the actual method output worked.  THANKS!

Comment: And what is `methodOutput.data` here then?

Comment: methodOutput is of type flask.wrappers.Response, and from what I understand .data() retrieves the data from the jsonify object.  all the examples of unit testing jsonify that I could find used a methodology similar to this.

Comment: `jsonify` returns a `Response` object, yes. [`Response.data`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.data) is a *descriptor*, not a method. You don't need to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Response.data` is a descriptor](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.data) and does not need to be called; you are trying to call the returned JSON string here.

Your better bet is to *decode* that JSON response; dictionaries are unordered and you should not count on what order the resulting JSON data is listed in. You already do so, but then you should compare that against a dictionary, not a new JSON string!

```
def test_get_ticket(self):
    with self.app.test_request_context('/?main_id=14522&user_id=82'):
        methodOutput = brain_get_ticket.get_ticket(
            {'main_id': {1: 0}, 'status': {'Closed': 0},
             'available': {'False': 0}},
            "main_id, status, available", ['main_id', 'status', 'available'])
        correct_return_output = dict(
            to_be_working_on_last_id=0,
            to_be_working_on_id=6,
            information={'status': {'Closed': 1}, 
                         'available': {'False': 1}, 
                         'main_id': {1: 1}})
        self.assertEquals(
            json.loads(methodOutput.data),
            correct_return_output, 
            "output was: {!r}, it should be {!r}".format(
                methodOutput.data, correct_return_output))
```